# vue.js - I'm getting an error when running my project

Tags: vue.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

```
sudo npm run serve

> frontend@1.0.0 serve /home/shinier01/Projetos/EstudanaIrlanda/frontend-estudenairlanda
> vue-cli-service serve

 INFO  Starting development server...
12% building 20/21 modules 1 active ...rojetos/EstudanaIrlanda/frontend-estudenairlanda/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/webpack/buildin/global.js/home/shinier01/Projetos/EstudanaIrlanda/frontend-estudenairlanda/node_modules/webpack/lib/Dependency.js:226
                throw new Error(
                ^

Error: module property was removed from Dependency (use compilation.moduleGraph.updateModule(dependency, module) instead)
    at ProvidedDependency.set (/home/shinier01/Projetos/EstudanaIrlanda/frontend-estudenairlanda/node_modules/webpack/lib/Dependency.js:226:9)
    at iterationDependencies (/home/shinier01/Projetos/EstudanaIrlanda/frontend-estudenairlanda/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:940:21)
    at factory.create (/home/shinier01/Projetos/EstudanaIrlanda/frontend-estudenairlanda/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:950:8)
    at factory (/home/shinier01/Projetos/EstudanaIrlanda/frontend-estudenairlanda/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:409:6)
    at hooks.afterResolve.callAsync (/home/shinier01/Projetos/EstudanaIrlanda/frontend-estudenairlanda/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:155:13)
    at _fn0 (eval at create (/home/shinier01/Projetos/EstudanaIrlanda/frontend-estudenairlanda/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:14:1)
    at fileExistsWithCase (/home/shinier01/Projetos/EstudanaIrlanda/frontend-estudenairlanda/node_modules/case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin/index.js:158:9)
    at that.fileExistsWithCase (/home/shinier01/Projetos/EstudanaIrlanda/frontend-estudenairlanda/node_modules/case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin/index.js:113:7)
    at that.fileExistsWithCase (/home/shinier01/Projetos/EstudanaIrlanda/frontend-estudenairlanda/node_modules/case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin/index.js:113:7)
    at CaseSensitivePathsPlugin.fileExistsWithCase (/home/shinier01/Projetos/EstudanaIrlanda/frontend-estudenairlanda/node_modules/case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin/index.js:83:5)
    at that.getFilenamesInDir (/home/shinier01/Projetos/EstudanaIrlanda/frontend-estudenairlanda/node_modules/case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin/index.js:106:10)
    at CaseSensitivePathsPlugin.getFilenamesInDir (/home/shinier01/Projetos/EstudanaIrlanda/frontend-estudenairlanda/node_modules/case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin/index.js:51:5)
    at CaseSensitivePathsPlugin.fileExistsWithCase (/home/shinier01/Projetos/EstudanaIrlanda/frontend-estudenairlanda/node_modules/case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin/index.js:89:8)
    at that.getFilenamesInDir (/home/shinier01/Projetos/EstudanaIrlanda/frontend-estudenairlanda/node_modules/case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin/index.js:106:10)
    at Array.fs.readdir (/home/shinier01/Projetos/EstudanaIrlanda/frontend-estudenairlanda/node_modules/case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin/index.js:67:5)
    at Storage.finished (/home/shinier01/Projetos/EstudanaIrlanda/frontend-estudenairlanda/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/enhanced-

    resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:55:16)
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! frontend@1.0.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Failed at the frontend@1.0.0 serve script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
    
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /home/shinier01/.npm/_logs/2020-11-10T18_21_27_165Z-debug.log
```

I tried to uninstall npm, vue and node, I deleted the .json files, but somehow nothing solves, and I always have this error when executing my command.

but this project is already running normally before, and now I gave an npm install and it updated the packages, but even if I give a roolbakc, or delete and install it again, nothing resolves.

```
    {
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A Vue.js project",
  "author": ".....",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
    "start": "npm run dev",
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@vue/cli": "^4.5.8",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.5.8",
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "buefy": "^0.9.3",
    "firebase": "^7.22.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.12",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props": "^2.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "^3.5.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.3.2",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "chalk": "^2.0.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^6.3.0",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "node-notifier": "^5.1.2",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "ora": "^1.2.0",
    "portfinder": "^1.0.13",
    "postcss-import": "^11.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.8",
    "postcss-url": "^7.2.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.0",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.6",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.1",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "vue-loader": "^13.3.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.2",
    "webpack": "^5.4.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.1.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 6.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

can someone help me solve this error, please?

Comment: Have you deleted your node_modules and retried an `npm i`?

Comment: try to update html-webpack-plugin dependency

Comment: Downgrade your webpack to v4, you are using vue 2 so there's no way to build this with webpack 5

Comment: For anyone still coming across this issue use a top-level `resolutions` to hard set the version of any dependencies that are in use along with any library versions you think might be causing issues. Then remove your package-lock.json and node_modules folder, then run `npm i` again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I faced the same problem and found a solution.

In my case application started using V5 of webpack and it was built on V4. You can run: `npm i -D webpack@^4.0.0` to reverse it to V4 and it should fix it.

Special thanks to Mark:
https://forum.layer0.co/t/error-module-property-was-removed-from-dependency/208